# What does Page() do in Razor Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I wonder why the handler `OnGet` of `IndexModel` can either be void or `return Page();`.

What does `Page()` actually do?

Comment: where exactly are you talking about? You mentioned razor pages and then mentioned returning something. Where did you use IndexModel ?

Answer (score 1):

*`What does Page() actually do?`*

```
return Page();
```

will show the same page again with requested validation.
But in many cases, validation errors would be detected on the client and never submitted to the server

Returning Page is similar to how actions in controllers return View.